# searching for text and only adding to list

Tags: java, loops, javafx, tableview

im looping through a table view and im adding whatever rows contains the text in a textfield i inputted. i have 5 fields but if i leave any search field empty it will return the tableview with all the items.

to actually find a row i have to fill in all text fields.

is there someway that i can can add just the rows that contain the values in the search fileds to the new list and not add all if one field is left blank.

heres my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i<table.getItems().size(); i++){

            if(     ((Person) table.getItems().get(i)).getName().toLowerCase().contains(personName.getText().toLowerCase()) ||
                    ((Person) table.getItems().get(i)).getAddress().toLowerCase().contains(personAddress.getText().toLowerCase()) ||
                    ((Person) table.getItems().get(i)).getPhoneNumber().toLowerCase().contains(personNo.getText().toLowerCase()) ||
                    ((Person) table.getItems().get(i)).getEmail().toLowerCase().contains(personEmail.getText().toLowerCase()) ||
                    String.valueOf(((Person) table.getItems().get(i)).getID()).toLowerCase().contains(personID.getText().toLowerCase()))
            {
                obList.add(table.getItems().get(i));    
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all

```
||
```

with

```
&&
```

in your if statement